# Como ocultar lista de opciones si no tengo nada escrito en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una lista de opciones que puedo seleccionar, al inicio se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces cuando escribo algo empieza a buscar, sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando borro lo escrito, no se oculta la lista, se queda abierto, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo principal es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Registro Mantenimiento</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/completar_formulario.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/completar_formulario2.js"> 
  </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sc.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sc2.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
                <span class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar producto' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal7"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"> 
  </i></a> 
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal7" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Editar Incidencia</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="editar_producto3" name="editar_producto3">
        <div id="resultados_ajax4"></div> 
        <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre_f" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Site</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_f" id="nombre_f" placeholder="Ingrese ID del SITE"  onkeyup="autocompletar();" autocomplete="off" onChange="es_vacio()" >
                <ol id ="lista" onclick="completar_formulario()"></ol>
            </div>
          </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="nombre_region" class="col-sm-3 control-label">NOMBRE DEL SITE: </label>
             <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="id2" id="id2" value="">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_region" id="nombre_region" placeholder="Ingrese ID del SITE" onkeyup="autocompletar2();" autocomplete="off" onChange="es_vacio()">
                <!---->
                <ol id ="lista2" onclick="completar_formulario2()"></ol>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sistema_enfriamiento_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DEPARTAMENTO: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="sistema_enfriamiento_1" name="sistema_enfriamiento_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" >
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="estado_rectificador_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">PROVINCIA: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="estado_rectificador_1" name="estado_rectificador_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" >
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="capacidad_modulos_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DISTRITO: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="capacidad_modulos_1" name="capacidad_modulos_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar_datos3">Actualizar datos</button>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

y el codigo js es de la siguiente manera:

```
function autocompletar() {

  //Aca vamos a realizar la funcion busqueda con Ajax. Llamamos al <id= lista> de la 
  //busqueda autocompletada. 

  var min_length = 0; // variable length
  var nombre_s = $('#nombre_f').val();//obtener el nombre y/o termino de busqueda
 if (nombre_s.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controlador/proceso_busqueda.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {nombre_s:nombre_s},
        success:function(data){
            $('#lista').show();//mistrar la lista
            $('#lista').html(data);//mostrar resultado de consulta en la lista
        }
    });
    } else {
    $('#lista').hide();
    }
  }

  // funcion que setea valores a los input despues de busqueda
  function set_item(id,item) {
  // setear valor al imput id y nombre
  $('#nombre_f').val(item);
  $('#id').val(id);

  // ocultar la lista
  $('#lista').hide();
}
```

ademas la lista de opciones que muestra desacomoda al siguiente input, en este caso esnombre site, habra alguna manera para que la lista salga por encima del input "nombre del site" y que se oculte si es que no he escrito nada??

Comment: Intentastes quitarle el >= y solo colocar >, es decir asi: `if (nombre_s.length > min_length) {`

Comment: si intente, pero aun asi me sale la lista, tmb puse que min_lenght=1 y no da

Answer (score 1):

Como el problema que planteas es el no poder ocultar y mostrar la lista avoluntad solo sustraje de tu codigo la lista, emule el resultado de la lista como si ya fuese llenada por el ajax y me enfoque en ocultarla y mostrarla bajo las condiciones que dices.

Hice dos ejemplos la primer con la clase de bootstrap **"d-none"** y como veras solo cuento el numero de caracteres que introduzco y dependiendo de eso muestro o no la lista:

```js
$("#nombre_f").keyup((e) => {

  var valor = $(e.target).val();
    
  if(valor.trim().length > 0){
  
    $("#lista").removeClass("d-none");
  }else{
    $("#lista").addClass("d-none");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nombre_f" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Site</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_f" id="nombre_f" placeholder="Ingrese ID del SITE" autocomplete="off" >
    <ol id="lista" class="d-none">
      <li>LI0493</li>
      <li>LI0294</li>
      <li>LI0070</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

La segunda como tu lo haces con el **hide** y el **show**:

```js
$("#lista").hide();

$("#nombre_f").keyup((e) => {

  var valor = $(e.target).val();
    
  if(valor.trim().length > 0){
  
    $("#lista").show();
  }else{
    $("#lista").hide();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="nombre_f" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Site</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_f" id="nombre_f" placeholder="Ingrese ID del SITE" autocomplete="off" >
    <ol id="lista">
      <li>LI0493</li>
      <li>LI0294</li>
      <li>LI0070</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cabe aclarar que lo tienes que adaptar a tu ajax porque solo me enfoque en el ocultamiento y en el mostrar de la lista ya que ese es la raíz del problema ademas que no tengo manera de probar tu ajax. Espero te funcione.